# Multiple method call using same client instance to WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, nettcpbinding

My WPF application is calling the WCF service using a single client object. This is working fine when request is sent and response is coming immediately before next request.

When I am sending the first request and it is taking 3 minutes to complete the calculation task and return the result. In the meanwhile second request is sent from my WPF application (ping request is sent every 3 second). At this time, I am getting the following error and WPF application getting disconnected:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply: this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a prematured session shutdown or an internal server error
>
> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

My service behavior is written as follows:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
```

I tried different combination and it is not working.

Comment: "My WPF application is calling the WCF service using a single client object." I guess you just found out while you need to change this. Create one per-call.

Comment: I tried PerCall and the concurrency mode as Multiple. It was throwing while first time connection with WCF service. Do you want me to keep Concurrency mode as single and try again?

Comment: I meant you need to create one client-side instance per call you want to make.

Comment: Yes it came to my mind. But the problem is, it is already existing application, I am adding a new feature to this. I can't change the everywhere. It is not allowed. Also, it is having callbacks, different threads calling WCF service(ping thread) etc. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you do multiple concurrent calls from singel client you should set ConcurrencyMode to Multiple in addition to InstanceContextMode ..
Note that if you set  InstanceContextMode to Single, your service act as singleton, Then you should be aware of manipulating variables because it has reflection on other calls ..

Comment: Yes, I have multiple concurrent calls for Single client. Also I tried InstanceContextMode as Single and ConcurrenyMode as Multiple. However, I am using only one Sevice Client object inside ServiceManager class to call service. Still it is getting WPF application is getting disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ping request should not use the same Channel. It should open it's own channel. Ideally, every independent request should open it's own channel (alternatively, you could build a queuing system). But accessing the same channel from two different threads is not going to work.